# Where'd the TestClient go?

Tags: wcf-web-api, asp.net-web-api

Where did the auto-generated test client go in ASP.NET Web API? (part of MVC 4 beta) In the WCF WebAPI it was in the global.asax:

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration() { EnableTestClient = true, EnableHelpPage=true };
RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<MyService>("api/path", config);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The test client is not part of ASP.NET Web API Beta (we had to pull it out due to limited time and architectural changes in the internal implementation). We are looking at bringing it back in the next release.

Comment: Sad face. I hope someone manages to put it into an "extras" or "contrib" package soon.

Comment: Bring it back please so i don't need to install fiddler or such app.

Comment: Please bring it back ... it was a huge time savings.